# ng-selected with ng-repeat in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry for asking again . But I cant set default value for select . Here is code I used

Plnkr

I cant use ng-options in this case . Please help me without ng-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the model has the value same as option defined, `ng-selected` would work as:

```
ng-selected="business_entity == businessConstants"
```

given the model is such :

```
$scope.formData = {business_entity : 'Công ty TNHH'};
```

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZD1F8GoQL0ERR4F1wi8?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the code in your controller as below,

```
$scope.formData={};
$scope.formData.business_entity = 'Công ty TNHH';
```

And please remove 'ng-selected' from your option tag from your tempalte.

```
<select ng-model="formData.business_entity">
  <option ng-repeat="businessConstants in businessConstants" value="{{businessConstants}}">
    {{businessConstants}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I've update your [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIoZAR9XFyBJ9pcwv3uw?p=preview) please check..

Answer (score 1):

remove `ng-select` and assign array reference to `ng-model` variable

```
$scope.formData = {
     'business_entity' : $scope.businessConstants[1]
}
```

Html

```
<select name="" id="" 
    ng-model="formData.business_entity">
      <option  
      ng-repeat="businessConstants in businessConstants" 
      value="{{businessConstants}}">
                                {{businessConstants}}
                                    </option>
    </select>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Phih17IGiheYS9cgzIHA?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select name="" id="" 
        ng-options="option for option in businessConstants"
        ng-model="business_entity">
    </select>
</body>
```

Your options will be automatically generated and the select will be bound to `business_entity` automatically

Change Controller to

```
function ctrl($scope) { 

  $scope.businessConstants = [
    'Công ty Cổ phần',
    'Công ty TNHH',
    'Tổ chức nhà nước',
    'Ngân hàng',
    'Trường học',
    'Cá nhân',
    'Khác'
  ];

  $scope.business_entity = $scope.businessConstants[4];
}
```

This will set the default value. Make sure you select the default value from the existing collection `businessConstants` and not assign it.

You can refer updated [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/G8HeRQV8mpIu8inacNMI?p=preview)